# No response while placing order with 2checkout

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I have a problem with 2checkout module in Magento. When I place the order with the help of 2checkout payment gateway I don’t get the response back of Payment completion. So, order status remains “Processing”. 
    I want to do something like when the payment completes it should response me back and the order status should be change to “complete”
    Please help… Thanks…

Comment: Magento help-desk question. Move to magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

The order status will change from pending to processing upon successful passback from 2Checkout. You can then utilize the "Invoice Automatically Before 2Checkout Fraud Review" or "Invoice Automatically After 2Checkout Fraud Review" setting in your Magento 2Checkout configuration to change the status to "Completed". These settings use the notifications sent by 2Checkout's Instant Notification Service so you will need to [setup your Notification URL](https://www.2checkout.com/shopping-cart/magento/) and enable the 'Order Created' and 'Fraud Status Changed' messages in your 2Checkout admin area under the notifications tab.

Feel free to contact 2Checkout Tech Support at techsupport@2co.com for assistance.